# PHP preg_match not matching with an expression to pattern

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this php code

```
if(preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id))
{
echo "Match found";
}
```

For `$id as 'BUTEqHLHxJSRr9DJZSMTN'` , its not working/matching.But I have tested the regex pattern online with the id and it worked.Please help me find the issue.

Thanks

Comment: you failed to close the if function. `if(preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id))`

Comment: can you post your full code how you getting id or what error you facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing parentheses for your `if` statement.

```
if (preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id))
                                          ^
```

**EDIT**: Your code and regular expression does work, see [**working demo**](https://eval.in/159221). Perhaps you have another issue somewhere else inside your code or your variable `$id` possibly contains something different.

As you can see, this returns a match.

```
$id = 'BUTEqHLHxJSRr9DJZSMTN';
preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id, $match);
echo $match[0]; //=> "BUTEqHLHxJSRr9DJZSMTN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that preg_match returns integer, not boolean. Proper if should look like:

```
if (preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id) > 0)
  {
    echo "Match found";
  }
```

Comment: *preg_match* returns 0, 1 or *false*. Since you don't want neither 0 nor *false*, the `> 0` is not necessary to catch a successful match.

Comment: @ring0 _preg_match_ returns _false_ only in case of error. We not going to feed bad regexp to it, do we? PHP is flexible about data types but being strict about types and explicit about values over time proven to be really good way of reducing number of bugs caused by automatic typecasting. Good programming habits will never go out of style :)